# what is the explanation of this "(x > 0) - (x < 0) || +x;" with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can we use a minus operator as a Comparison Operator ?

I couldn't find like a this situtation.

```
function sign(x) {
    return (x > 0) - (x < 0) || +x;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps to describe here.

### Compute sign (+1, 0 or -1)

As already noted in [Elia Soares's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72672312/479251), JavaScript implicitly converts boolean expression to numbers when doing a subtraction. `true` will be converted to 1, and `false` to 0.

```js
console.log(+true);
console.log(+false);

let x = 20;
console.log(+(x > 0));
console.log(+(x < 0));
```

then, doing `(x > 0) - (x < 0)` means:

- If x is positive, we get `1 - 0`, which gives `1`.
- If x is negative, we get `0 - 1`, which gives `-1`.
- If x is zero, we get `0 - 0`, which gives 0.

This looks already good to create a `sign(x)` function as [usually expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

[image: sign math function graph]

### Handle undefined

However, also consider `undefined` in this formula: any comparisons will give `false`, and so the above subtraction will give zero.

That's a bit dangerous, could be that you forgot to assign a value to the variable, which is a common bug when you write code.

That's why the  `|| +x` was added.

`||` in javascript means:

> Evaluate the left side. If it's *truthy*, return the left side. Otherwise, return the right side.

+1, and -1 are *truthy*, and 0 is *falsy*, so the full expression `(x > 0) - (x < 0) || +x` will evaluate to `+x` if and only if the subtraction gives zero.

If x is zero, this will still give +0 which is 0.

If x is `null`, this will give `+null` which is 0.

If x is `undefined`, this will give `+undefined` which is `NaN`.

Getting a `NaN` in your calculation will quickly cause all your subsequent results to be `NaN`, warning you that there was something undefined that you probably forgot.

Note that the `+x` still evaluate to `0` if x is `null` er empty string `''`, so this code won't change the (mayybe unexpected) result zero for those special cases.

Answer (score 3):

It will not act as a comparisons operator. It will act as a math operator. To this work, JavaScript converts the boolean resulting from the `x > 0` and `x < 0` to zero or one, then do the subtraction.

This is a weird code, but valid.